# How do I get the GRANT statements for a specified schema?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, pg-dump, dump

Is there a way to generate the `GRANT` statements that have been run on a schema in PostgreSQL, for example if `myUser` has been granted usage on `mySchema` the script would generate

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mySchema TO myUser;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pg_dump`

```
pg_dump -d myDatabase --schema mySchema --section=pre-data |
  grep '^GRANT'
```

If you want *just* the `GRANT` on the schema object.

```
pg_dump -d myDatabase --schema mySchema --section=pre-data |
  grep '^GRANT .* ON SCHEMA .* TO'
```

Comment: Yup this does exactly what I need to to do! Thanks a ton!!